# What is the difference between "noun", "proper noun", and "name"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning, nouns

Do *noun* and *name* carry a different meaning?
If there are any differences, are those differences specific to a context?

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems a perfectly valid question to me, especially for non-native speakers: in most languages that I know, the same word is used for both "name" and "noun" (e.g. French "nom", Arabic "اسم‎" ("ism")), and so it can be very confusing for speakers of those languages to have to choose between the alternatives.

Comment: @psmears: In Italian, _noun_ and _name_ are translated both with _nome_. It is funny (for me at least)  that _noun_ has origin from the Latin _nomen_ (_name_), and _name_ derives from an Old English word that shares its root wit the Latin _nomen_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think noun is a more general concept. All the names are nouns! On the contrary, not all the nouns are names! Also, we usually talk about nouns in grammatical context.

According to [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

**Noun:** a word or group of words that represent a **person** (such as ‘Michael’, ‘teacher’, or ‘police officer’), a **place** (such as ‘France’ or ‘school’), a **thing** or **activity** (such as ‘coffee’ or ‘football’), or a **quality** or **idea** (such as ‘danger’ or ‘happiness’). Nouns can be used as the subject or object of a verb (as in ‘The teacher arrived’ or ‘We like the teacher’) or as the object of a  preposition  (as in ‘good at football’).

**Name:** What someone or something is called such as 'Mandy'.

**Proper noun:** a noun such as ‘James’, ‘New York’, or ‘China’ that is the **name of one particular thing and is written with a  capital  letter**. It's also called proper name (*especially British English*).

**Common Noun:** in grammar, a common noun is any noun that is not the **name of a particular person, place, or thing**. For example, ‘book', ’sugar', and ‘stuff’ are common nouns.

Answer (score 3):

A noun (also *common noun*) is used to identify a group of people, places or things. A *proper noun* is used to name a particular one of these. *Name* is another word for *proper noun*, theoretically.