# Should broader types be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

I'm seeing that I get a red squiggle under the words *asian* and *european*. When I right-click either, it wants to capitalize the word. I wouldn't think a general type of thing gets capitalized, such as "evergreen tree", a type of tree, versus "Blue Spruce", a specific type. I would think I need to capitalize "Chinese" or "German" or "American", but not the broader types of "Asian" or "European".

Comment: They are all Earthlings to me...and I capitalize that. But then, I am from Neptune.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “noun”, “proper noun”, and “name”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11445/what-is-the-difference-between-noun-proper-noun-and-name)

Comment: No matter how "clever" the grammar checking software in your word processor is, you should never use its 'squigglies' as an authority  on how to use the language.

Comment: @DominicCronin - Very true, that is why I came here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All proper nouns need to be capitalized. I believe you are puzzled over whether "Asian" is a proper noun or not. I don't see why not. We need to define what a [proper noun is:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun)

> A proper noun or proper name is a noun representing a unique entity (such as London, Jupiter, John Hunter, or Toyota), as distinguished from a common noun, which represents a class of entities (or nonunique instance[s] of that class)—for example, city, planet, person or corporation).

Now, I believe you think that "Asian" is too broad a noun to be called a proper noun, because it seems to represent a class of entities, that is, a group of various people, such as Spanish, French, etc.

Does that mean, however, that we shouldn't capitalize "Europe", but should just write it as "europe"? Of course not. "Europe" still refers to a specific place, a continent, and "Europeans" refer to a specific people, the people that come from Europe. And there's only one group of people that comes from Europe, the Europeans.

Comment: *Asia* is a proper noun; *Asian* is a proper adjective.

Answer (score 1):

When using 'Asian' as an adjective, yes, it is capitalized based on the following logic:

"In general, an adjective is capitalized if its meaning is "pertaining to X", where X is some specific person, place, language, or organized group. Most capitalized adjectives are derived from proper nouns; for example, the proper adjective American is derived from the proper noun America."

In this case, Asian and European are proper adjectives, and are therefore capitalized.

Comment: Can you provide the source of the quote?

Answer (score -2):

Europe and Asia are the proper names of continents. It doesn't matter how general the term is, they are all humans but that isn't the name of the species so isn't capitalised. Homo-Sapiens is the species proper name so is capitalised.

Comment: The same as tree -> evergreens -> Blue Spruce I would have thought it would be humans -> asians -> Chinese or humans -> euopean -> Germans. Generally set -> sub-set -> specific type. I could see globe -> continents -> Asian.

Comment: It's *Homo sapiens*: genus is capitalised; species is not. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_nomenclature

Comment: @CesarGon - opps, not quite sapiens enough !

Comment: @Martin Beckett: :-)