# Correct way?: most abundant 10 african and 10 european ingredients

Tags: grammatical-number

Lets say I want to talk about the 10 ingredients most frequently found in each continent, while being as concise as possible. I have the choice to say `10 most abundant ingredients in african and european continents`, but then it becomes unclear whether the 10 are the sum of both, or 10 in each, and how they are split. How would you say this?

Comment: There are many different ways of saying this e.g. *The 10 most abundant ingredients in each of Europe and Africa*, *The most abundant 10 ingredients in both the European and African continents*, *The 10 most abundant ingredients in Europe and in Africa* etc.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to repeat *in* to disambiguate:

> 10 most abundant ingredients in the African and in the European continents.

Answer (score 1):

Adding *both* adds some clarity:

> 10 most abundant ingredients in **both** African and European continents.

This is perhaps still not 100% (although I would use "*across both*" instead of "in" or "in both" if I meant 10 in total). However, I would expect the rest of the article to remove any doubt about which is meant.

Also, depending on what you are writing about, I might say "*cuisine*" instead of "*continents*" – depends on whether you are talking more about what is *grown* there or what is *eaten* there (there may be differences).

Finally, note that both African and European should have initial capital letters (see [Should broader types be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/41776/102510)).

Comment: "Adding *both* adds some clarity:" How?

Comment: @Kris Because I see "_in both X and Y_" as short-hand for "_in X and in Y_".

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm commenting here just to clarify or get things much clearer that you need to add **both** to easily indicate ohh there's two continents he meant. SO, it would be **10 Most Abundant Ingredients in both African and European Continents**, and once again, that structure is quite common in use which is actually what you are expecting. Thank you

Comment: Yes, indeed, you are. Please use comments, if you have the privilege.